# Issue with xml to object c# using Xml.Serialization

Tags: c#, xml

I have an old xml response and I cannot map it to an object as I normally do.

- Using paste special> xml
  :When I deserialize it, it's throwing "The specified type was not recognized: name='Array'"
- Using class from https://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/
  :I can map to object but there is nothing in return property

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:tns="http://uat.api.sample.uk">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns1:directReportResponse xmlns:ns1="urn:Direct">
            <return xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array" SOAP-ENC:arrayType="tns:DirectResult[1]">
                <item xsi:type="tns:DirectResult">
                    <TMSReference xsi:type="xsd:string">sampleTMS</TMSReference>
                    <Postcode xsi:type="xsd:string">samplePostcode</Postcode>
                    <ExpectedDelivery xsi:type="xsd:string">2020-08-25</ExpectedDelivery>
                </item>
            </return>
        </ns1:directReportResponse>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

After follow andyrut, I can map it to custom type but still no value in an item obj

Comment: Do you have a code sample of how you're deserializing the string?

Comment: public static T XmlDeserializeFromString<T>(string objectData)
        {

            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            T result;

            using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(objectData))
            {
                result = (T)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
            }

            return result;
        }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generated class does not know that a "return" tag is an array of "item" elements. You simply need to make the following modifications to your C# class:

1. Delete the class definition for Return.
2. Mark the Return data member as a list/array of Item's. Change the Return data member in the DirectReportResponse to a list and decorate it like so:

   `[XmlArray(ElementName="return", Namespace="")]`
   `[XmlArrayItem(ElementName="item", Namespace="")]`
   `public List<Item> Return { get; set; }`
3. There's a Type specified in the Item XML, so decorate your Item class by adding the following line above it:

   `[XmlType(Namespace="http://uat.api.sample.uk", TypeName="DirectResult")]`

You may need to tweak your C# class for the other specified types in the XML file.

Comment: Hi andyrut, I'm able to map it to directResult custom type. It does recognise item list but no value passed across; TMFReference, Postcode and ExpectedDelivery are null. I added the current code in the original post

Comment: You’ll need to apply the XmlType and TypeName to each of those classes that currently show up null.